# Retrieve data from one column in one row

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a class (table) in `Parse.com` core data called `users` with `username, name, surname, email` and `password`.

I want to retrieve, for example, only the `name` column but I can't make this work. Here is the code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"user"]; //1
    [query  whereKey:@"email" equalTo:_labelEmail.text];//2
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *userData, NSError *error) {//4
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", usuario);
        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];
```

I know `userData` is an array not a dictionary but then how can I retrieve only the information I want? I did try to pull the `userData` as a dictionary instead of an array but the query does not let me do that.

What I want to do is something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", userData["name"])
```

Comment: What is Parse.com core data? Never heard of it.

Comment: Its the database of Parse.com, where you make your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check if your returned array is empty.  If it is then no matter what you do you are not going to get the information you need out of the query.

If you are getting an error you should probably think about your query class.  You are trying to query on the class "user" whereas I'm guessing you would like to query the built in _User class.  To do that you would use a different kind of query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

Try this query type that Parse gives for this exact purpose and see if your returned data has any valid data.  If it does you can either use:

```
PFUser *user = [userData objectAtIndex:0];
```

if you know that there should be only one user object returned to you, or you can use:

```
for(PFUser *user in userData)
{
    //Do something with the user object that got returned to you
}
```

Comment: I saw the _User class but im just trying to learn, because when i used custom class i`ll not have the same options as using the build _User class.

I already done the PFUser *user but when i try to NSLog(@"%@", user) he returns me the whole array not only my email (or whatever im trying to get).

Comment: If you get a user object, then you just have to request the key from that user object.  So get the user from the array using the line I mentioned about (objectAtIndex:), then pull the email key by `user[@"email"];`

Comment: I cant believe, i already done that 1h ago but i totally forgot the @. What a dumb mistake. Thanks man. =)

Comment: @Luke i know your new to SO, but it's common sense to give someone the credit they deserve. For accepting answers that work and solve your particular issue, you should click on the check mark under the vote up/down buttons next to the answer. This creates a more efficient SO community and also shows future answers that you accept them if they are the correct ones

Comment: I know. Sorry about that Putz and soul. I though i had clicked on the correct answer button. Thx for remind me. =)